# Is there any difference between sql server that comes with VS2008 and sql server express 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any difference between sql server that comes with visual studio 2008

and sql server express 2008 ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Visual Studio 2008 comes with SQL Server Express 2008. It **IS** SQL Server Express 2008 - the whole, full, complete, absolutely identical thing to what you can download.

By now, there are four editions of SQL Server 2008 Express:

- SQL Server 2008 Express - Runtime only - that's the one bundled with Visual Studio 2008
- SQL Server 2008 Express - Management Tools Add-On (SQL Server Management Studio Express)
- SQL Server 2008 Express - Runtime + Management Tools (combination of the two above)
- SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services (Reporting Services and Fulltext Search and including the Management Tools)

But the copy included in VS 2008 is indeed the full "SQL Server 2008 Express - Runtime only" package - no difference, no compromise, no "scaled-down" version or anything.

Comment: Man, you should at least consider keeping a few adjectives in your hand to later retreat from your statement if it's proven as not absolutely correct :-)

Comment: @CDR: I'll find or make up new ones if needed :-)